# Ruby On Rails - missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner and I'm stuck on this: I'm building a messaging function and I want to search through the messages (referred to here as chatrooms) by typing in the first name of someone - it should then show all messages between the current user and that name. Currently I'm trying this in my chat_rooms_controller.rb:

```
def index
if params[:query].present?
  my_chatrooms = ChatRoom.where(requester: current_user).or(ChatRoom.where(receiver: current_user))
  sql_query = " \
    my_chatrooms.requester.first_name ILIKE :query \
    OR my_chatrooms.receiver.first_name ILILKE :query \
  "
  @chatrooms = ChatRoom.where(sql_query, query: "%#{params[:query]}%")
else
  @chatrooms = ChatRoom.where(requester: current_user).or(ChatRoom.where(receiver: current_user))
end
```

end

Not entering any params works and lists all my ongoing conversations. But as soon as I enter anything into the searchfield I get this:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
> "requester"

I don't have a table called "requester". Requester is just a column in my chatrooms table. After looking through similar posts here I tried a Join with the "profiles" table (which has a user's first_name), unfortunately that didn't work either.

Utterly stuck here, would be grateful for any pointers and please excuse my rookie code

Comment: What is `my_chatrooms.requester.first_name`? I think you are trying to match the user's first name with the search query. The syntax you are trying to use would not work in SQL as it is Rails syntax. You will have to join with the `users` table and then match the `first_name` if you wish to do it with SQL.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do. Thanks for pointing out that mistake! my users table does not have a first_name column, but my profiles table does, so I've tried this, unfortunately no luck yet: sql_query = " \
        profiles.first_name ILILKE :query \
      "
      @chatrooms = ChatRoom.joins(:profile)where(sql_query, query: "%#{params[:query]}%")

Comment: i guess you maybe need to join the nested join users-profile `ChatRoom.joins(users: :profile)`

Comment: Thanks Lam Phan, tried that out but no luck unfortunately :(

Comment: @Brednad you also need to change `sql_query`: `profiles.first_name ILIKE :query ...`